# nested iterator struts2 - batch insert hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2, insert, iterator, bulkinsert

Hi I want to  submit my form  using `struts2 hibernate 3` who contain  nested  iterator but I can't diference between all attribute name 
i m trying to use a global variable in my jsp lik  that :

```
<% int i=0; %>
<form  name="evalform" action="saveOrUpdateSousEval"    method="post"  >    
<s:iterator value="CategListGrille"  status="catgStatus">
     <s:iterator value="type"   status="typeStatus">
             <s:iterator  value="item" status="itemstatus" >
                    <s:textfield value="66" name="%{'souseval[#i].SousEval_Note'}"  />
                    <% i++;  %>
             </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator> 
    <s:submit value="Evaluer"  cssClass="btnsubmit"   /> 
    </div>  
</form>
```

in my class Action i have this  :

```
private ArrayList<SousEvaluation> souseval= new ArrayList<SousEvaluation>(); 
public String saveOrUpdate(){   
        System.out.println("enter saveOrUpdateEvalNote ok");    
        sousevaldao.saveOrUpdateSousEvaluation(souseval);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

and in my class Dao  i have :

```
@Override 
    public void saveOrUpdateSousEvaluationNote(ArrayList<SousEvaluation> sousevalnote) {
        try {
            for (Iterator<SousEvaluation> it = sousevalnote.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                                      session.saveOrUpdate(it.next());
                 }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
```

my goal is to  submit many obect at once using my form

I can submit many record at once when i only use  one iterator like  that  : i make  this exmape i's  work fine

```
<form  action="saveOrUpdateSousEval"    method="post"     > 
<s:iterator  begin="1" end="2" status="status">
            <s:textfield     name="%{'souseval['+#status.index+'].SousEval_Note'}"   />
        <s:textfield name="%{'souseval['+#status.index+'].evalglb.Eval_ID'}"    />
        <s:textfield name="%{'souseval['+#status.index+'].sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID'}"  />

</s:iterator>
 <s:submit value="Evaluer"  cssClass="btnsubmit"   /> 
 </form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't, there's no access to such variables.

Comment: why not using the index property of the inner iterator's status ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A very bad coding style mixing struts tags with scriplets. Infact never use scriptlets. Let the view be clean.

I read the question twice, and you've already written the solution yourself. What's the problem ?

```
<s:iterator value="CategListGrille"  status="firstIter">
     <s:iterator value="type"   status="secondIter">

<s:textfield name="souseval[%{#firstIter.index}].sousEvalItem[%{#secondIter.index}].SousItem_ID'}"  />
<s:textfield name="souseval[%{#firstIter.index}].sousEvalItem[%{#secondIter.index}].SousItem_Name'}"  />
<s:textfield name="souseval[%{#firstIter.index}].sousEvalItem[%{#secondIter.index}].SousItem_Description'}"  />
```

Action can have something like :

```
private List<List<sousEvalItem>> lst;
```

If you can explain your question more clearly, I might be able to provide a targetted solution.

Comment: I found a way to differentiate the name , but I can't insert multirecord i'll  update my question to  new question

Comment: i changed my question

Comment: well I still don't understand what exactly is the question ? It seems what you are trying to save is NULL, that means the form didn't submitted successfully. Did you tried logging in what's going or checking the request being sent ?

Comment: Yeh my form submit null  but i m not khow how fix it

Comment: `name="%{'souseval['+#n+'].evalglb.Eval_ID'}"` what format is this ? Also, have you seen my answer, I've already mentioned how to use both iterators in the name !

Comment: Yes i see it ,but isn't work for me  and i have also created a lis like this  private ArrayList<SousEvaluation> souseval= new ArrayList<SousEvaluation>(); and  i don't need to create another list  private List<List<sousEvalItem>> lst;  how  can i create one list when used nested iterator

Comment: https://github.com/nitincool4urchat/Struts2 - It contains few struts2 examples including nested iterators & object form submissions.

Comment: thank you brother I'll see the example and  and I will answer you for it

Comment: wow Thank you for your  help  I found  a solution   now i can  insert multiple record with  nested iterator  ussing globale variabl like that   <s:set name="n" value="0"/> and  
name="%{'souseval['+#n+'].SousEval_Note'}" 
<s:set name="n" value="%{#n+1}"/>